# Adding a tracking pixel to outlook 2010

Tags: html, outlook

I am trying to add an Image to outlook 2010.

Lets say the image source is http://image.com/image.gif

So I was adding it as an attachment and then "insert as text" because its a tracking pixel and the image is 1*1 pixel,

It should show up in the view source of the email body something like "src="http://image.com/image.gif" but instead it shows up as "src="cid:image001.gif@01D1D871.A3495050" and hence the tracking pixel doesn't work

I have this working on different PC but there must be some setting in outlook which could handle this use case

Comment: unless the recipient allows remote images to be displayed, the pixel would be useless anyways. no modern client allows remote images to be displayed, exactly for this reason - it's a privacy violation.

Comment: This is an internal tracking within our company and this is just to track number of hits an communication email gets

Answer (score 0):

Here almost 5 years later, but the text you are inserting should not be 'http://image.com/image.gif' if that is the image. You should create a separate page that includes the image. For example, make 'http://image.com/text' with these contents on the page:

```html
<img src="http://image.com/image.gif">
```

When you go to insert as text, outlook will grab the contents of that whole page and insert it into your email.